# Search common items in 2 lists in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, list

I have 2 columns (input & target) in the pandas which includes the list. The purpose is to find how many common item in these 2 lists and save the result in the new column "common"

For the 1st row, only have 'ELITE' in common. For the 2nd row, both 'ACURAWATCH' & 'PLUS' exist in both list.

Input:

```
frame = pd.DataFrame({'input' : [['MINIVAN','TOURING','ELITE'], ['4D','SUV','ACURAWATCH','PLUS']], 'target' : [['MINI','TOUR','ELITE'], ['ACURAWATCH','PLUS']]})
```

Expect Output:

```
frame = pd.DataFrame({'input' : [['MINIVAN','TOURING','ELITE'], ['4D','SUV','ACURAWATCH','PLUS']], 'target' : [['MINI','TOUR','ELITE'], ['ACURAWATCH','PLUS']], 'common' :[1, 2]})
```

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`set.intersection`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_set_intersection.asp) with [`df.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

```
In [4307]: frame["common"] = frame.apply(
lambda x: len(set(x["input"]).intersection(set(x["target"]))), 1)

In [4308]: frame
Out[4308]: 
                         input               target  common
0    [MINIVAN, TOURING, ELITE]  [MINI, TOUR, ELITE]       1
1  [4D, SUV, ACURAWATCH, PLUS]   [ACURAWATCH, PLUS]       2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can apply a custom function with `np.intersect1d`:

```
frame['common'] = frame.apply(lambda x: len(np.intersect1d(x['input'],x['target'])), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
frame['common'] = [len(set(x) & set(y)) for x, y in frame.to_numpy()]
print(frame)
```

**Output**

```
                         input               target  common
0    [MINIVAN, TOURING, ELITE]  [MINI, TOUR, ELITE]       1
1  [4D, SUV, ACURAWATCH, PLUS]   [ACURAWATCH, PLUS]       2
```